# how to make a download button to retrieve pdf file in sql database?(java swing)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, pdf

Good day everyone! I am trying to create a desktop application using java swing wherein the user can upload pdf files to the mysql database. I already did the upload part in the application, but I'm having trouble on making a download button in the application. The function of the `download` button is to retrieve the `pdf` file in the mysql database and then download it in the user's computer.

here's what I found in inserting pdf file from https://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/69-jdbc/845-how-to-storeretrieve-pdf-document-tofrom-sqlserver.html 
The above link has already a function in getting pdf data, but I can't seem to understand how to implement it in my download button.

```
  public void upload(Connection conn,String filename) {
        int len;
        String query;
        PreparedStatement pstmt;

        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            len = (int)file.length();
            query = ("insert into fileStorage VALUES(?,?,?)");
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1,file.getName());
            pstmt.setInt(2, len);

            //method to insert a stream of bytes
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(3, fis, len); 
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What I'm having a trouble is making a function for my download button. how do I retrieve the file from database and download it at the same time after clicking the `download` button.

Comment: clarify on what part you have trouble: creating a button, setting an action on a button, getting and element from the database, storing something on local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so unfortunately I don't know your table format however we should be able to create a prepared statement that gets the file raw bytes from the database. The following will get the byte array from the database and then create a new file, if necessary, from the raw bytes.

1. Change fileName to the proper name of the column for the file name.
2. Change fileContent to the name of the column for the byte array.
3. Make sure fileContent is a varbinary type.
4. Replace null in my reference to download(Connection, String) with a legitimate non-null Connection reference.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            byte[] download = download(null, "test");

            Path output = Paths.get("my", "output", "file.pdf");

            Files.write(output, download, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Uh oh something went wrong!", e);
        }
    }

    static byte[] download(Connection connection, String fileName) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM fileStore WHERE fileName = ?")) {
            statement.setString(1, fileName);

            try (ResultSet results = statement.getResultSet()) {
                if (results.next()) {
                    return results.getBytes("fileContent");
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("No file can be found for this name.");
    }
```

Comment: I get an error in `Path` and `StandardOpenOption` and so I imported the following `import java.nio.file.Files;` , `import java.nio.file.Path;` , `import java.nio.file.Paths;` , `import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;` did I import the right class? the errors are gone but I still can't understand if the code run successfully because I still haven't seen the retrieve file in the computer. and btw, what does `Path output = Paths.get("my", "output", "file.pdf");` mean?

Comment: Those are the correct imports. Did you make the necessary changes that I pointed out? main(String[]) would throw an exception if something went wrong. Look for the file at the top-level, not in /src/main/resources.

Comment: Sorry this is actually what happened, The first thing that I did is to make a class `download.java` and then I paste the codes in the main and the static on the outside of the main method. changed the things that needed to be changed and then after running the code I got an error in the console `Error: Could not find or load main class app.download`   and then I paste the code `static` in gui file while the codes in the `main` goes to the `button`.  and then I run the code and get no error but don't know where to look for the retrieved file.

Comment: I apologise but unfortunately I cannot help you further with this.